# Can I define flex tokens during runtime?

Tags: lex, csv

I'd like to use lex/yacc to read in a delimited text file. This would be pretty trivial stuff for a parser, but different text files have different delimiters, so I'd like to let the user specify whether the text is separated by tabs, spaces, commas, pipes, [unicode snowmen](http://unicodesnowmanforyou.com/), et cetera.

The normal means of using these tools is to write a spec for lex and yacc, compile, and then use the static code for parsing. But is there a way to let the user specify the delimiter (and thus redefine the tokens) at run time?

I'm currently using flex/bison, but am open to suggestions of small and portable alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to do this. Lex and Yacc create the lexer or parser tables as part of a C program, so you can't alter it after it has been created.

It's not exactly clear what format you need to parse, so without examples I won't make any suggestions.